# Convert JSONArray to array of objects

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using Unirest to receive responses from REST calls. The responses may look like:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "It worked",
    "data": [ { ... }, { ... } ]
}
```

Depending on the API call I've hit, the class of data stored can vary between dozens of objects or arrays of those objects. This is handled on the server side by using generics.

But when I try to use Unirest's .asObject class, the data section actually gets turned into an ArrayList (that part's perfect) of HashMap objects (not so great).

If I use a non-template (non-generic) class such as:

```
public class Response_MyObjectArray { ... ArrayList<MyObject> data ... }
```

That works. But I don't really want to create a few dozen non-generic classes to handle this.

So... I can readily use `.asJson()` instead. This returns a `JsonNode`, which I can query and get a `org.json.JSONObject`. Great so far.

I can then get the `data` object, which will be an `org.json.JSONArray`. Still great so far.

Can I use Jackson to translate that back into an `ArrayList<MyObject>`? I think I can do this readily if I do something like this:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> foo = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<MyObject> array = objectMapper(jsonArray.toString(), foo.getClass());
```

It seems crazy to have to convert back to a string just to do the object mapping. It's also a little strange to have to create an empty array so I can call `getClass()`, but you can't do `.class` on generics. Plus I'm not entirely sure that's going to work.

What I'd really like is to just use a generic:

```
RestResponse<ArrayList<MyObject>> resp = objectMapper(stringOfJson, RestResponse<ArrayList<MyObject>>.class);
```

but that doesn't work for the several reasons above.

Solutions that don't involve creating about 100 versions of RestResponse_MyObject?

Answer (score 0):

You can download a library called Gson from Maven, my recommends to create HashMap.

Gson helps to parse json object.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After this try to make this example of code:

```
String jsonString = "{'employee.name':'Bob','employee.salary':10000}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Map.class);
```

Comment: I'm long familiar with gson. But you're still parsing a string, not an already parsed complicated object into a template class.